# Can this work to have users' files encrypted so that only the user can decrypt and view the files?

Tags: encryption, php

I want to make some kind of file vault. I want to store encrypted files in a MySQL table, and the key to encrypt/decrypt them is never stored but only known to the user (that's the goal, anyway).

The user has to be logged in to view a list of his files. Then, to view a file, the user has to enter a key to decrypt a file to read it. So assuming a user's account was hacked and his password was discovered, I want the hacker to still be unable to decrypt the files, since the hacker doesn't know the key used to encrypt it.

What are the biggest holes in this? Please help me improve it rather than just saying 'this is terrible'. I know the security of this depends on other code that I didn't put here. I just tried to put the most relevant parts.

Here is some code from the controller to add a new file:

```
    public function addFile($request, $response) {

        $user = Security::getUser();
        if (!$user) { $this->denyAccess('add-file'); }

        $unencrypted_content = $request->getParam('content');
        $key = $request->getParam('key');
        if (Security::authenticate($user->username, $key)) {
            $this->flash->addMessage('error', 'You can not use your password as the key to your files.');
            return $this->redirect('new-file');
        }

        $otherFile = $user->files()->first();
        if ($otherFile && !Crypt::decrypt($otherFile->content, $key, $otherFile->iv)) {
            $this->flash->addMessage('error', 'The key you entered failed to decrypt another one of your files. You must always use the same key.');
            return $this->redirect('new-file');
        }

        $iv = Crypt::iv();
        $encrypted_content = Crypt::encrypt($unencrypted_content, $key, $iv);

        $file = new File;
        $file->owner()->associate($user);
        $file->name = $request->getParam('name');
        $file->content = $encrypted_content;
        $file->iv = $iv;
        $file->save();

        return $this->redirect('all-files');
    }
```

Here is the Crypt class:

```
public static function iv() {
    $letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $iv = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
        $iv .= substr($letters, rand(0, 35), 1);
    }

    return $iv;
}

public static function encrypt($content, $key, $iv) {
    return openssl_encrypt($content, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
}

public static function decrypt($content, $key, $iv) {
    return openssl_decrypt($content, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
}
```

And again in the controller to view a file:

```
public function viewFile($request, $response) {
        $csrf_name = $request->getAttribute('csrf_name');
        $csrf_value = $request->getAttribute('csrf_value');

        $file = File::find($request->getAttribute('id'));
        if ($file->owner->id !== Security::getUser()->id) { $this->denyAccess('view-file/' . $file->id); }

        $key = $request->getParam('key');
        $decrypted_content = Crypt::decrypt($file->content, $key, $file->iv);

        if (!$decrypted_content) {
            $this->flash->addMessage('error', 'The key you entered is not valid.');
            return $this->redirect('authorize', ['id' => $file->id]);
        }

        $file->content = $decrypted_content;
        $file->key = $key;

        return $this->render($response, 'file/view.html.twig', compact('file', 'csrf_value', 'csrf_name'));
    }
```

Comment: How do you plan to not store the _user key_ anywhere?  There has to be something to reference it against.

Comment: This seems more fitting for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: using rand() for iv generation is not good... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280769/how-to-securely-generate-an-iv-for-aes-cbc-encryption

Comment: Presuming you passwords are hashed in the database when checking with Security::authenticate(). Even with that you have provided an attacker an interactive test for a bruit force attack?

Comment: At the end of viewFile() ... $file->key = $key;  why are you storing the private key in the $file object at this point.. I hope your not reflecting it back to the user?

Comment: Users are likely to select the same key to encrypt all files simply because it's easy for them to remember.

Comment: Consider man in the middle replay attacks. Check your not sending the same key data over the wire each time. Here's an idea... user hashes key a random number of times (n where n < 50000) and sends hash & n to the server. Server hashes 100000 - n times. So the total is always 100000. Double down by getting the server to generate n first.

Comment: regarding `$file->key = $key` - I'm not 'saving' the file, but just setting that property before rendering the view, which will contain the key, so that the user can edit/delete the file without having to reenter the key. The key will be in a hidden input (i know not really hidden) in forms.

Comment: Yes, users are likely to select the same key, because they are required to. I tried to require it in addFile.

Comment: so one important improvement would be to use the users key as a master key to encrypt random strings you use as keys to the individual files. store these encrypted keys along with the files in your db, and reflect these unencrypted keys back  to the user in your hidden fields instead of the users master key.

Comment: you could also implement the creation and encryption/decryption of individual file keys in client-side javascript. This would protect against some attacks that tried to steal the master key in transit or on the server side, since the master key wouldn't need to be sent to the server at all. It wouldn't be secure against MITM with ability to change traffic or against a compromised server, though.